# Replace a row in a pandas dataframe with values from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am trying to populate an empty dataframe by using the csv module to iterate over a large tab-delimited file, and replacing each row in the dataframe with these values. (Before you ask, yes I have tried all the normal read_csv methods, and nothing has worked because of dtype issues and how large the file is).

I first made an empty numpy array using np.empty, using the dimensions of my data. I then converted this to a pandas DataFrame. Then, I did the following:

```
with open(input_file) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,delimiter='\t')
    row_num = 0
    for row in reader:
        for key, value in row.items():
            df.loc[row_num,key] = value
        row_num += 1
```

This is working great, except that my file has 900,000 columns, so it is unbelievably slow. This also feels like something that pandas could do more efficiently, but I've been unable to find how. The dictionary for each row given by DictReader looks like:

```
{'columnName1':<value>,'columnName2':<value> ...}
```

Where the values are what I want to put in the dataframe in those columns for that row.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried pandas.read_csv() or considered using a database?

Comment: @SebNik I have tried pandas.read_csv(), I got a dtype warning because there are NA's in my dataframe (setting low_memory = False as a fix seemed like a bad idea), and then it's as slow if not slower than what I've done above -- can't tell because I haven't been able to get it to finish running. I also tried using dask.dataframe, and I get the same warning/slowness when I try to execute any kind of computation on it, even just df.head()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you could do in this case is to build smaller chunks of your big csv data file. I had the same issue with a 32GB Csv-File, so I had to build chunks. After reading them in you could work with them.

```
# read the large csv file with specified chunksize 
df_chunk = pd.read_csv(r'../input/data.csv', chunksize=1000000)
```

chunksize=1000000 sets how many row are read in at once

Helpfull website:

https://towardsdatascience.com/why-and-how-to-use-pandas-with-large-data-9594dda2ea4c

Comment: I tried this as well and it didn't work... but my file is only 1.6GB so it should...

Comment: Okay, what didn't work was there an error or something like that ??

Comment: I get a dtype warning for every column (I think this is because I have NaN's), and then nothing else happens, and after 10 or so minutes I just killed it.

Comment: So I've been playing around and it seems like the reason chunksize doesn't make much of a difference in terms of memory or speed is because my dataframe has many many more columns than rows. Thoughts on how to work with that?

Comment: I mean you could only read some columns in so just select a few every chunk.

Comment: but what if I need all of them? I was able to use pandas.read_csv on a subset of the columns, but I need eventually to have read them all in. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: You could try to read them in a SQL-Database, there it should work faster. Bu also maybe have multiple pandas dataframes and work them with them. Shouldn't make a difference it is just more complicated. If that answers your question please mark it as solved.